# how to redirect struts2 action to a url after validation?

Tags: validation, url, redirect, struts2

I have a action with a url creation like this

```
if (this.sequence.equals("") ) {
       action= "input";
   } else {url = "/files/" + testHTML.getName();
         action= "redirect";

    }
      return action;
```

in my struts.xml my action is declarated has

```
        <interceptor-ref name="completeStack"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait">
            <param name="delaySleepInterval">500</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="wait">testwait.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">test.jsp</result>
         <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${url}</result>
    </action>
```

When I launch the application, the url is created but there are no redirection to this new page but to the test.jsp page and I have the validation error message that appear. Anybody have some idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your original code example looks correct. Here are a few things to check:

- Does your action have a `getUrl()` method? The `${url}` part of the result relies on that method to get the `url` property.
- Have you verified that the correct result is returned in each case? e.g., 'redirect' in the else block and 'input' otherwise.

Comment: Yes I have a getUrl() method and correct result is return in each case...when I log my java action, I have a link for the url page but in my jsp in debug mode, the same value (url) is "null" during the action process

Comment: Try setting a break point in `ServletRedirectResult` to see if its getting to the redirect.

Comment: ok, the code still working, the problem come from the execandwait interceptor

Answer (score 0):

if you are using validate method and if there is validation errors struts return result name="input". In your case put redirect in

```
     <result name="input" type="redirect">${url}</result>
```

Comment: the url (a HTML page)  is created only if they are no errors in the action and what I want, is to see this new page

Comment: As I can see what are you trying to achive, at first you can redirect to another action, but you want to display just different jsp page so why not try like this <result name="displayPage">${dynamicPage}</result> where ${dynamicPage}="pathToThePage"